# Factorization of an Upper Triangular Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U$ be an $m$ x $m$ upper triangular matrix.  Let $U_j$ be the matrix obtained by replacing the $j$th column of $I$ with the $j$th column of $U$.  Prove that $U=U_mU_{m-1} \cdot\cdot\cdot U_1$.

My first thought is to use the definition of matrix multiplication, but it seems quite complicated.  Is there an easier way to approach this problem?

Comment: Use induction to show that for each $i \in \left\{0,1,\ldots,m\right\}$, the matrix $U_i U_{i-1} \cdots U_1$ has the same entries as $U$ in its first $i$ columns and the same entries as $I$ in its last $m-i$ columns. And yes, the definition of matrix multiplication is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Writing $u_i$ to be the $i$th column of $U$, show that $U_j u_i = u_i$ for $j > i$. That is, $(U_j - I_m) u_i = 0$. If you don't want to get messy with matrix multiplication, this can be shown by realizing that $e_1, \ldots, e_{j-1} \in \ker (U_j - I_m) $. Thus $u_i \in \text{span}(e_1, \ldots, e_{j-1})$ implies $u_i \in \ker(U_j - I_m)$.

From here we see that $U_2 U_1$ for example can be written as
\begin{align}
U_2 U_1 &= U_2 [ u_1 \ e_2 \ \cdots \ e_m]\\
&= [U_2 u_1 \ U_2 e_2 \ \cdots \ U_2 e_m]\\
&= [u_1 \ u_2 \ e_3 \ \cdots \ e_m],
\end{align}
where $e_i$ denotes the $i$th standard basis vector. The property where multiplying a matrix by the $i$th standard basis vector "picks" the $i$th column from the matrix is used. That is, $A e_i = i$th column of $A$. Continuing by induction allows us to conclude
$$ U_m U_{m-1} \cdots U_1 = [u_1 \ u_2 \ u_3 \ \cdots \ u_m] = U.$$